# fatal error: X11/extensions/XIproto.h: No such file or directory #include <X11/extensions/XIproto.h>

Tags: c++, linux, qt

A `make` of `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0` on OpenSUSE 13.2 after `./configure -qt-xcb` fails with the following:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_TSLIB -DQT_NO_LIBINPUT -DQT_BUILD_XCB_PLUGIN -DXCB_USE_XLIB -DXCB_USE_RENDER -DDFLT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=\"/usr/share/X11/xkb\" -DDEFAULT_XKB_RULES=\"evdev\" -DDEFAULT_XKB_MODEL=\"pc105\" -DDEFAULT_XKB_LAYOUT=\"us\" -DQT_BUILD_XCB_QPA_LIB_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQ_FONTCONFIGDATABASE -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLATFORMSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Igl_integrations -I../../../3rdparty/xcb/include -I../../../3rdparty/xcb/sysinclude -I../../../3rdparty/xkbcommon -I../../../3rdparty/xkbcommon/xkbcommon -I../../../3rdparty/xkbcommon/src -I../../../3rdparty/xkbcommon/src/xkbcomp -I../../../3rdparty/xkbcommon/src/x11 -I../../../../include -I../../../../include/QtPlatformSupport -I../../../../include/QtPlatformSupport/5.7.0 -I../../../../include/QtPlatformSupport/5.7.0/QtPlatformSupport -I../../../../include/QtGui/5.7.0 -I../../../../include/QtGui/5.7.0/QtGui -I../../../../include/QtGui -I../../../../include/QtCore/5.7.0 -I../../../../include/QtCore/5.7.0/QtCore -I../../../../include/QtCore -I.moc -isystem /usr/include/libdrm -I../../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qxcbxsettings.o qxcbxsettings.cpp
qxcbxsettings.cpp:49:36: fatal error: X11/extensions/XIproto.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/extensions/XIproto.h>
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile.xcb_qpa_lib:7354: recipe for target '.obj/qxcbxsettings.o' failed
make[6]: *** [.obj/qxcbxsettings.o] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/jan/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb'
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'sub-xcb_qpa_lib-pro-make_first-ordered' failed
make[5]: *** [sub-xcb_qpa_lib-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/jan/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb'
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'sub-xcb-make_first' failed
make[4]: *** [sub-xcb-make_first] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/jan/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms'
Makefile:99: recipe for target 'sub-platforms-make_first' failed
make[3]: *** [sub-platforms-make_first] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/jan/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/src/plugins'
Makefile:641: recipe for target 'sub-plugins-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jan/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/src'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jan/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase'
Makefile:77: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `inputproto-devel`:

```
sudo zypper install inputproto-devel
```

and restart the configuration and build.